# How to catch the "tab changed" event in a property sheet

Tags: c++, wtl, propertysheet

How to catch and handle the notification about that the currently selected tab has changed in the class derived from CPropertySheetImpll? I added TCN_SELCHANGE handler to message map but a peoperty sheet has never recieved this notification. I use wtl and write in c++.

Answer (score 2):

Property sheet sends [PSN_SETACTIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [PSN_KILLACTIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774559%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to notify on changed pages (valid for both regular and wizard property pages).